# in @Query , I need to query DB to select a row where a column is null. I am using JpaRepository

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have tried using below query

```
@Query(value = "select E.SRC,E.TRGT,E.EVNT_STTS,E.ADDL_ATTR from EVNT.EVNT_LOG E where E.EVNT_ID=:eventId and E.ADDL_ATTR IS NULL" , nativeQuery = true)
List<AggregationLog> findByEventIdAndTargetAndAdditionalAttributeWithNULL(@Param("eventId") Long eventId);
```

in above query I am getting invalid column name.

Please guide me to select a row with eventID and addl_attr as null.

Comment: Looks fine. does this query work if you execute it  insql-developer/sql plus?

Answer (score 0):

Well... invalid column means oracle cannot resolve the column name in the query. That usually means 1 of 2 things:

1. A Typo
2. The columns were created with case sensitivity. Whoever created the table surrounded the column names with double quotes and put column names in something other than all caps. Do a "DESCRIBE <table_name>" in sqlplus, sqldeveloper or any other client and check if the column names are all upper case. If they're not, you will need to enclose them in double quotes in your query with the name matching exactly what you see.